# Accessing a filename in PHP using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] or http://www

Tags: php, file, document-root

I am trying to access a files in PHP. I build the filename by saying:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/soundbites/images/image001.jpg'
```

... this returns

```
/home2/example/public_html/soundbites/images/image001.jpg
```

If I use this in my program the image cannot be located, but if hard code the image, as:

```
http://www.example.org/soundbites/images/image001.jpg
```

... then it all works as expected.

Am I making a schoolboy error, or is there a difference between the two ways of accessing the files that I am missing.

Comment: Where are you calling the image from? Where at in your folder hierarchy?

Comment: in frontend, you should go from relative .. e.g. say your `page1.php` is in `app -> templates` and your images are in `skin -> images` then you should use `/skin/images/image-name.jpg` - using `/` on unix servers equates to document root.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns the filesystem path *to* the document root; files, such as images, on the website are accessed *from* the document root - you'll probably never want to use the filesystem path on the frontend.